# How to get data from branch included in list in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As shown in the picture I have campaign branch which is a dynamic list where I save every campaigns data.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16xe1aeAxEbtfiiUFoXtlqvFPucHejQp7/view?usp=sharing

Every campaign data includes location which is an other branch inside the campaign,
I want to get location data of all campaigns.
I tried it using the code below but it return null value.

```
void getCampaignsLocations(final OnGetDataListener onGetDataListener){
        onGetDataListener.onStart();
        Toast.makeText(this, "started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DatabaseReference campaignsRoot = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference campaignsPath = campaignsRoot.child("campaigns");
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    LatLng l = ds.child("location").getValue(LatLng.class);
                    campaignsLocations.add(l);
                    onGetDataListener.onSuccess(dataSnapshot,0,"");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        campaignsPath.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    }
```

Comment: it's built in in google play map,
i also tried to do this but it didn't work
String latitude = String.valueOf(ds.child("location").child("latitude").getValue(Double.class));
but it returns null
i think the problem with calling the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference campaignsRef = rootRef.child("campaigns");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            double latitude = ds.child("location").child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
            double longitute = ds.child("location").child("longitute").getValue(Double.class);
            Log.d(TAG, latitude ", " + longitute);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitute);
            //Do what you need to do with your LatLng object
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
campaignsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Please note, that in order to create a `LatLng` object, you need to loop throught the `DataSnapshot` object to get the `latitude` and `longitute`. There is no way you can map the children that exist under the `location` node to a `LatLng` object. Beside that, `LatLng` is **not** a [Firebase supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

Comment: it worked but the value that is gotten from firebase still equal null 
i am storing all values in a list and when trying to display it in a toast that happens
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nuf6MEObFUODv_0nVbJrRw7jyLudNwqD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I cannot understand much from that screenshot. Please provide a more explicit one, to see more code. Are trying to get the Toast outside the `onDataChange`?

Comment: exactly trying to get the Toast outside the onDataChange

Comment: i am saving every result in LatLng list called campaignsLocations and want to test the data already received

Comment: Trying to Toast that message outside the `onDataChange` is problem related to the fact that Firebase APIs are asynchronous. For more informations, you can check **[How to return DataSnapshot value as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** out.

Comment: great thanks, the problem that i am trying to call it from List object
when i replaced it with ArrayList it worked